# List of automatically installed updates on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I need to check what has been installed on remote Ubuntu server by package security channels.

How could I do that in bash?

For manually installed I could check:

- /var/log/dpkg.log
- /var/log/apt/history.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package **unattended-upgrades** install software automatically (Default: only security updates). You can find the logs in:

> /var/log/unattended-upgrades

The official documentation: [Automatic Updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html)

You can custom the [Automatic security Updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates)